# Not getting contact Id in custom button Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not getting Contact ID in my javascript custom button that I have created in Quote 
the button exist in Quote Line Item Page

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 

getMsg(); 
function getMsg() { 

newwindow=window.open('apex/multiAttachment?qotId={!Quote.Id}&mId={!Contact.Id}','height=500,width=550'); 
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()} 
return false; 
}
```

Comment: you have to explicitly query the contact from quote record

Comment: Or use {!Quote.ContactId} if available

Comment: Is that my answer solved your purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this type of code. Please mind those single or double quotes.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

var recordId = '{!QuoteLineItem.Id}';
var quoteRec = sforce.connection.query("select QuoteId, Quote.ContactId from QuoteLineItem where Id='" + recordId + "'"); 
alert('quoteRec=' + quoteRec);

var vcontactId = quoteRec.records.Quote.ContactId;
var qotId = quoteRec.records.QuoteId;
alert('vcontactId=' + vcontactId);
```